Cannot uninstall @angular/core
I cannot unistall @angular/core even if I ran the command 'npm uninstall -g @angular/core'
When running the command 'npm info @angular/core version' it keeps showing version 18.1.1

You shouldn't and likely don't have Angular core installed globally as a primary package. The thing you probably want to uninstall globally is the cli: npm uninstall -g @angular/cli. It would only make sense to remove @angular/core from a specific project (and even then you're unlikely to want to do that). You are likely seeing the @angular/core cli dependency when you run the npm info command.

If I already ran npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
and when running 'npm info @angular/core version' why do I still see 18.1.1 ?|
it is not supposed to be removed when running npm uninstall -g @angular/core too?>
I want to uninstall angular core version 18.1.1 because it is not compatible in my project

@BradleyBousoula This sounds like XY problem. You aren't supposed to install it globally because it's not CLI package, and even if you did, globally installed package doesn't affect project deps. Consider reasking the question with the actual problem you have instead of trying to address a wrong way to solve it. "'npm info @angular/core version" - probably because you run the command in a project that has this dependency?

What's interesting is I just tried uninstalling the cli and checking the core version with npm info and for whatever reason it does still show up wherever npm info is checking. Since https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands doesn't list npm info it would be non-trivial to figure out where that's actually looking. @EstusFlask is definitely right that it won't be affecting your project @BradleyBousola. I'd suggest posting the compatibility error in your question.

@SomeoftheThings It's an alias of npm view which just fetches package data and not related to installed packages at all. The OP probably confused it with npm list. As said, it's xy problem
